# How to deserialize params received as JSON string in controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am using Rails to write a controller receiving JSON as its params, and then testing it with an Rspec request spec.

controller:

```
class API::UserController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render json: { errors: @user.errors.full_messages }, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :name, :password_digest)
  end
end
```

spec:

```
RSpec.describe "User creation", type: :request do
  def create_user_request
    params = { user: build(:user), format: :json }
    post api_users_path, params: params.to_json
  end

  it 'should create a new user' do
    expect { create_user_request }.to change { User.count }.by(1)
end
```

But this fails with:

```
     Failure/Error: params.require(:user).permit(:username, :name, :email, :password_digest)

     ActionController::ParameterMissing:
       param is missing or the value is empty: user
```

I think the issue is that `params` in the controller is a serialized JSON object as a string. If I replace `params: params.to_json` with `params: params` in my spec, then the `user` params becomes the string `"#<User:0x.....>"`.

How do I make the spec and the controller play nice together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first issue is that you need to convert the model into a hash (not stringify it). The easiest way to do that is using `.attributes` i.e.

```
build(:user).attributes
```

I'm also not sure if you should be passing `format: :json` as part of the params, but I think it will depend on which version of rails, rspec etc you are using, but for rails 4 what works for me is

```
post api_users_path, user: build(:user).attributes, format: :json
```

Comment: Thank you, can't believe I spent so much time on this issue!